# For LOOP and random choice prints one string from a list

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, random

For some reason my list doesn't get printed completely, but only word by word each time I run the script.

```
import random

passwords = ['test', 'password', 'heslo', 'lol']

var = random.choice(passwords).split()

for word in var:
    print word
```

I wish the `for loop` to print my whole list in randomized order each time I run my script. Upon removing `random.choice` it works, but list is not randomized.

Comment: @Carcigenicate split prints each word in line, if I don't use split it prints letter by letter on each line after the whole word is printed out

Comment: @Carcigenicate i know split doesnt print, but it puts the whole word in the same line. shuffle seems to not work

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `choice` only selects a single random element from the list. I believe you meant to use `shuffle` instead. `shuffle` randomizes in-place the order of the list passed to it:

```
import random

passwords = ['test', 'password', 'heslo', 'lol']

# Randomize the order of the list
random.shuffle(passwords)

for word in passwords:
    print word
```

This will alter `passwords`. If you want the original list to remain unaltered, make a copy of it first:

```
pass_copy = passwords[:]  # Slice copy
random.shuffle(pass_copy)

for word in pass_copy:
    print word
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this indeed fixed it. After removing the `var` it's working great

Comment: @uzdisral No problem. Glad to help.